# tab layout with viewpager is blocking control

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager, android-tablayout

i had created an android apps using TabLayout and ViewPager and using FragmentPagerAdapter

```
                <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                    android:id="@+id/a"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:tabMode="scrollable"
                    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"/>

                <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                    android:id="@+id/b"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@id/a">
                </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@id/b"
                    android:text="@string/about"/>
```

the EditText wth never show in screen even all of the control is cover by ScrollView

i have no idea what cause this

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<RelativeLayout ...
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

               <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                    android:id="@+id/a"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:tabMode="scrollable"
                    ...
                    />
               <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/text"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:text="@string/about"/>

               <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                    android:id="@+id/b"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_above="@id/text"
                    android:layout_below="@id/a">
                </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: but i want display the text below the content of tab layout for all tab

Comment: You want in order from top to bottom: 1.Tabs Layout 2. Common Text 3. Scrollable ViewPagerContent?

Comment: EditText for all tabs ? Could you please draw you expectaions)